# Allow gameObject to access a gigantic Dictionary of data without using a Singleton?

Tags: c#, dictionary, unity-game-engine, singleton

I have a gameObject in Unity that I want to be able to access a random entry in a gigantic Dictionary of data.

I currently have it working by using the Singleton pattern for a gameObject that contains the Dictionary, and a getter:

```cs
public class VectorData : MonoBehaviour
{
    // create singleton
    public static VectorData i { get; private set; }
    private void Awake()
    {
        i = this;
    }

    // gigantic Dictionary containing Lists of Vector2's (real project will have hundreds of entries)
    Dictionary<string, List<Vector2>> dataDictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<Vector2>>()
    {
      {"dataSet1", new List<Vector2> {new Vector2(-1, 6), new Vector2(0, 6), new Vector2(1, 6)} },
      {"dataSet2", new List<Vector2> {new Vector2(-7, 6), new Vector2(-6, 6), new Vector2(-5, 6)} }
    };

    // getter
    public Dictionary<string, List<Vector2>> DataDictionary
    {
        get => dataDictionary;
    }

}
```

And another gameObject will get that data by accessing it as so:

```cs
public class CoolObject : MonoBehavior
{
    public List<Vector2> vectorInfo;

    private void Awake()
    {
       // get a List of Vectors from the VectorData singleton
        vectorInfo = VectorData.i.BattleDictionary["dataSet2"];
    }

} // end CoolObject Class
```

But since only `CoolObject` needs access to this Dictionary, using a globally accessible singleton seems like overkill.

So my question is, **what is the best and most performant way for an object to have access to a gigantic dictionary (or any large set of data) like this?**

Things I considered:

- The object itself could obviously store the data, but this Dictionary is so gigantic that it will be unruly inside of any script that has any other code in it.
- The same applies for creating a parent class to pass this information down (`CoolObject` already inherits)
- I know Scriptable Objects are often used for data, but from my understanding they are mostly used as a base to create new objects from?
- Maybe I'm completely wrong and a Singleton is actually the best approach here?

I'm still fairly new to Unity so I'm really trying to develop good habits and techniques. Any help here is really appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure that's a singleton?? I don't use Unity but I've seen several questionss on Stack Overflow where state is lost because, it turns out, `MonoBehaviour`-derived classes get instantiated every frame or whatever, so your (non-static) `dataDictionary` field would get initialized repeatedly, not to mention all the lists it contains (and also `i` would be reassigned to the latest instance every time that happens).

Comment: Well, I was pretty sure it was until you brought up these good points. I know there are multiple ways to set up a singleton, and this was just the most recent & compact way I saw from some youtube tutorial. I'll do some more research on it, thanks for alerting me.

Comment: @madreflection no it would be extremely inefficient if a `MonoBehaviour` would be instantiated each frame ^^

Comment: What about simply having a `static class` which holds and provides a `static Dictionary` ? Or in generalake the dictionary `static` so it is shared among all instances of your type? (Infact it is part of the type itself and doesn't belong to any instance)

Comment: If your concern is the global accessibility you could put both classes that need to have access into one assembly (see [Unity Assembly Definition](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ScriptCompilationAssemblyDefinitionFiles.html)) and make it `internal`

Comment: @derHugo, from what I can see based on some of these comments is that I currently *do* have a static class with `VectorData` here. What would be the difference between declaring that class `static` directly, and the way I've done it in my original post?

Comment: The difference would be that you don't depend on `Awake` nor does it have to be attached to any `GameObject` but rather simply "exists" such as e.g. `Physics`, `Input` etc in Unity

Comment: @derHugo I ended up using `static class` & `static Dictionary`. But I'm wondering what you meant by "Or in generalake the dictionary `static` so it is shared among all instances of your type"?

Comment: @damon oh that's justy fat fingers :D It was supposed to say `in general make` ^^ what I mean was it would probably be enough to have it as `static Dictionary<string, List<Vector2>> dataDictionary = ...` this was it doesn't have to be in a separate `static class` and also it doesn't have to be available `public` to anyone .. it can stay in the very same class but basically all instances of that class have access to the same dictionary instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to convert my comment into an answer now to be able to write it better and with more explanation ;)

To refer to your mentioned points

> The object itself could obviously store the data, but this Dictionary is so gigantic that it will be unruly inside of any script that has any other code in it.

That's a bit opinion based. If that data belongs to one certain class and no other class should access it I don't see why it shouldn't live inside that class even if there is more code in there. If you are concerned about readability you could still simply wrap it in a foldable [`#region`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives#defining-regions) or use a [`partial` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/partial-classes-and-methods).

> The same applies for creating a parent class to pass this information down (CoolObject already inherits)

Well this **could** be done by having e.g. a

```
public abstract class VectorDataMonoBehaviour : MonoBehaviour
{
    protected readonly Dictionary....
}
```

and than rather let your other class derive from that

```
public class CoolObject : MonoBehaviour 
{
    ... 
}
```

**But** let's face it .. how uncanny is that! And everytime you then want to also have another data type for a specific class you would be screwed again ;)

> I know Scriptable Objects are often used for data, but from my understanding they are mostly used as a base to create new objects from?

Yeah in a case where you only want one of such an asset exist anyway, using `ScriptableObject` doesn't make much sense.
**Except** if you want to be able to easily switch out the data with different values without having to recompile your application! In this case `ScriptableObject` would be **the** thing to use!

> Maybe I'm completely wrong and a Singleton is actually the best approach here?

In this case I would say **no!** In contrary. Singleton is quite controversial anyway but **if** you use it it comes with some huge drawbacks:

- you need to rely on the Singleton instance being initialized => on `Awake` being called => You always have to make sure such an instance actually exists in your scene, is active and enabled, and doesn't get destroyed ever even when changing the scene (or you have to reinitialize everytime).
- you would also rely on the `Awake` of this type being called **before** anything ever tries to access the Singleton instance

---

I'm your use case instead of thinking about Singleton or not you can simply make the dictionary itself [`static`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static) which makes it a part of the type itself and not anymore bound to a certain instance of it. See also [Static classes and static members](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members)

```
public class VectorData : MonoBehaviour
{    
    //gigantic Dictionary containing Lists of Vector2's (real project will have hundreds of entries)
    private static Dictionary<string, List<Vector2>> dataDictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<Vector2>>()
    {
      {"dataSet1", new List<Vector2> {new Vector2(-1, 6), new Vector2(0, 6), new Vector2(1, 6)} },
      {"dataSet2", new List<Vector2> {new Vector2(-7, 6), new Vector2(-6, 6), new Vector2(-5, 6)} }
    };

    // getter
    public static Dictionary<string, List<Vector2>> DataDictionary => dataDictionary;
}
```

This way you don't rely on any instance existing in your scene, active and enabled. You also don't rely on the order and that/if `Awake` was already called for this instance.

No, instead the `dataDictionary` simply already exists during the entire lifetime of your application.

---

However, since your class now seems to not hold anything instance based and nothing related to one specific `GameObject` it is questionable why it should be a `MonoBehaviour` at all.

If a class only has `static` members then make the entire class `static`

```
public static class VectorData
{    
    // Note if your property is doing nothing else you could as well
    // simply make the field readonly itself
    public static readonly Dictionary<string, List<Vector2>> DataDictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<Vector2>>()
    {
      {"dataSet1", new List<Vector2> {new Vector2(-1, 6), new Vector2(0, 6), new Vector2(1, 6)} },
      {"dataSet2", new List<Vector2> {new Vector2(-7, 6), new Vector2(-6, 6), new Vector2(-5, 6)} }
    };
}
```

This way it can not be attached to any `GameObject`. It just "lives" in your `Assets` folder.

---

Just another hint if your really want to just hardcode the data and then nobody should be able to ever modify it you might want to rather use an [`IReadonlyDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ireadonlydictionary-2) and let it store [`IReadonlyList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ireadonlylist-1) like e.g.

```
public static class VectorData
{    
    public static readonly IReadonlyDictionary<string, IReadonlyList<Vector2>> DataDictionary = new Dictionary<string, IReadonlyList<Vector2>>()
    {
      {"dataSet1", new List<Vector2> {new Vector2(-1, 6), new Vector2(0, 6), new Vector2(1, 6)} },
      {"dataSet2", new List<Vector2> {new Vector2(-7, 6), new Vector2(-6, 6), new Vector2(-5, 6)} }
    };
}
```

This is possible because `Dictionary` implements `IReadonlyDictionary` and `List` implements `IReadonlyList`.

This way you convert it in an immutable data provider and nobody can modify any of it's content.

Comment: What an awesome answer! I feel like when I originally asked this question, I was confused about what I was actually looking for. But I think you were able to decipher it and provide the information that I really needed. I'm glad you were able to confirm here that what I really should have done is store this data in `static` class. I didn't know about `readonly`, which is a nice bonus. If I had to ask 1 follow up, it would be, how is `IReadonlyDictionary` different than a `static readonly Dictionary`? And what is the `I` here - Immutable? (Are they related to `IEnumerator`s?)

Comment: @damon the difference is that `readonly Dictionary` means you can not change the dictionary instance reference itself .. but still the content! An [`IReadonlyDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ireadonlydictionary-2) is an **interface** (that's what the `I` usually stands for in c#) which only provides methods to access data but no way to change it => `IReadonlyDictionary` makes absolutely sure the content can not be changed and the additional `readonly` makes sure the reference can not be changed ;)

Comment: @damon and again the inner `IReadonlyList` makes sure that the content of the lists also can only be accessed but not changed afterwards

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! So just to make sure I'm getting it, `IReadonlyDictionary` is exactly the same as `Dictionary`, except that the content cannot be altered once it's defined? (And same for `List` vs `IReadonlyList`)?

Comment: @damon almost yes ;) The underlying `Dictionary` is still a normal dictionary. **BUT** since there is no way another class can access it since you only provide the `IReadonlyDictionary` interface it basically means you only provide access to the read methods => no other class can write anything to the dictionary. So basically yes this achieves that the content is absolutely immutable afterwards

Comment: Thanks for all your help @derHugo, you've made me a better Unity developer :)

Answer (score 2):

Some thoughts.

You are making the variable static, which not the same as creating a Singleton. Singleton pattern involves a unique instance that is static, but what you do I would call it make the variable static.

You don't need to make the variable static to grant access from outside. Property with public getter is fine.

Making the variable static in c# means that the property value will be the same in all `VectorData` instances(if more than one) . Meaking it a class property instead of an instance property, so part of the class template itself.

Regarding your points 1 and 2, the amount of code in a class has no relation with how big your data structures are. Logic or arquitecture will be written according to readability and logic functionality, not to data structures size use.

Point3. Check the usage of scriptable objects in the [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-ScriptableObject.html). Large amount of raw data is OK as you have it in a class variable.

Point4
Singleton pattern or making the property static seems overkill to me. To access one class property, public get is fine, or a public variable.

Finally you should not worry about performance due to large amount of data when a class instance is passed around, because class instances are passed by reference, so you are no making any copies of your huge dictionary.

Hope that makes sense :)

Comment: Thanks for sharing your thoughts. Since there will only be one instance of `VectorData` (since it's just a place to store data), is there a difference if I make it `static` or not? For points 1&2, the idea here is for better readability, so at least I had that idea right. For a ScriptableObject, I guess I don't like the fact that there needs to be an asset created for the data to be accessed - since this is essentially a database, it seems weird to create a game asset for it? Again, thank you for taking the time to help educate me :)